# SharePoint 2010 Workflow restarts itself where it should wait

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a pretty simple SP2010 Workflow created in SharePoint Designer. The Workflow is set to start when an item is created. It sets some fields on the current item, sends an email and then is supposed to wait for a field to be not empty. For some reason the workflow is not waiting for that field to change, instead it restarts itself which looks like this in the workflow history:

```
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Values set! 
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Email sent! 
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Waiting on Assigned To  
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Values set! 
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Email sent! 
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Waiting on Assigned To  
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Values set! 
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Email sent! 
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Waiting on Assigned To  
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Values set! 
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Email sent! 
28.12.2011 16:47    Comment System Account  Waiting on Assigned To
```

After 4 cycles its stops going crazy and waits for the field to change as its supposed to be. Everything else after this wait works fine...

Any Ideas why this is happening?

P.S.: Assigned To is a User/Group field created by me.

**UPDATE:**

I've tracked the issue down to an assignment of the "Title" field of the current item.
I have a Choice Field with 3 options and I'm allowing "FillIn-Choices" as well.
In the workflow I set the "Title" field of the current item (which is set to be not Required) to the value of the choice field. If I remove this action the workflow does not do the loop. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Since it only repeats four times, could that be the amount of fields you are updating in the item? Try posting some screenshots of your rules.

Edit: I reproduced your details and the problem did not occur(first with dropdown+fill-in then with checkboxes+fill-in), a suggestion would be to try assigning the value from the choice column into a variable before setting the title field.

My attempt to isolate the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpspG.png

Configuration database version: 14.0.4762.1000 (RTM)

Comment: Please check the Update section above

Comment: I've already tried the variable method. Didn't work :( I've now discovered that it only happens if the workflow is set to start when an item is created. It works fine if I start it manually. How did you do it? Did you make the Title field not required and left it empty when you created a new item?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using SharePoint 2013 with legacy workflow.
I am using an OnItemAdded reciever, which does nothing else, but starts the workflow (Workflows won't start with "Item Added" checked when an anonymouse user creates a list item. This is the work-around.)
I figured that this problem only occures when the workflow is started by the reciever. When I start it manually, it runs fine. I don't understand, why.

This is what I did to prevent it from restarting 4 times: I added a field to the list, called it WorkflowStatus. In the workflow, I start with a condition: if WorkflowStatus <> "done" then set it "done", and do the rest of the job.

I know it's kind of late, but I hope it helps someone...